# The marker position doesn't update

Tags: android, google-maps-markers

I wrote this code to try to update the marker position. The position is MY current position.
But doesn't move! It moves only the little blue ball.

This is the important code:

```
private LocationListener mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d(TAG_LOG, "In onLocationChanged(...)");
        showMapFragment();
    }
};

/*Metodo che si occupa di mostrare la mappa nella UI che invochiamo quando
  la location è disponibile.*/
private void showMapFragment() {
    Log.d(TAG_LOG, "In showMapFragment()");
    Fragment existingMapFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(MAP_FRAGMENT_TAG);
    if (existingMapFragment == null && mCurrentLocation != null) {
        Log.d(TAG_LOG, "Nell'if di showMapFragment");
        //Creo il map fragment
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = new CallbackMapFragment();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.anchor_point, mapFragment, MAP_FRAGMENT_TAG);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG_LOG, "Nell'else di showMapFragment");
        //Otteniamo il riferimento alla GoogleMap
        mGoogleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) existingMapFragment).getMap();
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        //Impostiamo il tipo di mappa
        synchMapType();
        //Creiamo ed aggiungiramo il marker
        final LatLng newLatLng = new LatLng(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(), mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());
        if(mHereMarker == null) {
            Log.d(TAG_LOG, "Creo il marker relativo alla mia posizione.");
            final MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            markerOptions.position(newLatLng).title("My Position")
                    .snippet("[" + newLatLng.latitude + "," + newLatLng.longitude + "]");
            mHereMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        }
        else {
            Log.d(TAG_LOG, "Aggiorno la posizione del marker..");
            mHereMarker.setPosition(newLatLng);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

1- create a alarm manager.

2- schedule time interval for update.

3- send broadcast and check location in onrecieve method of broadcast reciever.

4- set marker accordingly.